# Force google to always return [placeholder] ads

Tags: responsive-design, adsense

When making various changes to websites layout and testing them, it is very desirable to see all ads loaded, however Google generally (or so it seems) only loads ads if it thinks it finds something suitable for you. Is there some way (maybe request parameter?) that would force google to always return some place-holder ads that would not be checked against anything (location, page content, visitors history)?